# Issue with a generated URL

Tags: php, url, server

I have an issue with a URL. 
I have a download link generated this way:

```
$cwd = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/"));
$a = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."$cwd/file.php?q=$token";
```

And it was working fine for months. Some weeks ago this link stopped working and I only managed it to start work again by replacing `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."$cwd`  with my actual site address like this:

```
$a = "http://www.example.com/myfolder/file.php?q=$token";
```

Do you have any ideas what may be the problem?
Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: So what do you have now with this code? What's the output of `$a`?

Comment: My site is hosted at Bluehost, so the output of `$a` is:   `http://box498.bluehost.com/~examleco/myfolder/file.php?q=1f4d99d494a2fbc677d3cbb3d135adb8`

Answer (score 0):

server_name comes to php from web server (apache or nginx or smth else):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Probably your web server settings has changed. Anyway, it is not a reliable way to determine your site domain. You can store it in site configuration.